# DexGuard 7 and Retrofit 2 error

Tags: android, obfuscation, retrofit2, dexguard

In my app I use retrofit 2 for the network communications.
I have a serverAPI interface which contains every api request for example:

```
@Multipart
@POST(V2__ACCOUNT__UPLOAD_AVATAR)
Call<UploadAvatarResponse> uploadAvatar(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

I use Dexguard 7.2.09 to obfuscate my application, and every network communication is working expect one!

I really don't know what is wrong.

I see in the debugger that when the application call this request the code jump into the onFailure() method, but the app doesn't send the request to the server.

If I don't obfuscate the application everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using callbacks, you might need to add the following:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

Comment: I added but its not help for me

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Proguard in your project add the following lines to your configuration:

```
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

source :http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I added but its not help for me